# calculating values in excel using sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I've tried sumproduct and i've tried sumif but I think what I need is a combination (or a better understanding of sumproduct)

Here is my data

> state | percent
>
> NSW | 0
>
> NSW | 20
>
> VIC | 0
>
> SA | 0
>
> WA | 15
>
> NSW | 0
>
> NSW | 70

What I want to try and calculate is as follows:

- Where state = NSW

AND

- Where percent > 0

I want to work out the average of the matched values

By including values = 0 I can use:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"NSW",B:B)/COUNTIF(A:A,"NSW")
```

But now I want further define by removing the 0 values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this

criteria total/criteria count approach

*assumes your dataset is in A1:B7, please update as necessary*

**All Excel versions**

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A7="NSW"),--(B1:B7>0),B1:B7)/SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A7="NSW"),--(B1:B7>0))`

**Excel 07/10 only**

`=SUMIFS(B1:B7,B1:B7,">0",A1:A7,"NSW")/COUNTIFS(B1:B7,">0",A1:A7,"NSW")`

Comment: I've always used multiplication in my Sumproduct formulas, and until just now hadn't realized that the " ,B1:B7" part avoids the #VALUE error I'd get by using " * B1:B7".  I've always worked around it by not including the header in Sumproduct, I knew about using commas instead, just never realized this benefit.  +2!

Comment: @DOugGlancy thx Doug, it is the coercion of the TRUE / FALSe values to 1 / 0  respectively by use of the double negative `--` that allows the standard SUMPRODUCT construct of `,`

Comment: I actually tried the sumproduct but had the syntax wrong. Working perfectly now - thanks

Comment: I thought that, butSUMPRODUCT((A1:A8="NSW ")*(B1:B8>0),B1:B8)/SUMPRODUCT((A1:A8="NSW ")*(B1:B8>0)) works, whereas =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A8="NSW ")*(B1:B8>0)*B1:B8)/SUMPRODUCT((A1:A8="NSW ")*(B1:B8>0)) yields #VALUE.  The only thing different is the one comma.

Comment: @DougGlancy Yep, quite right. That is because the `(A1:A8="NSW ")*(B1:B8>0)` component has been coerced by the multiplication so it can be combined with a "," with `B1:B7` as you did.  Whereas this fails `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7="NSW"),(B1:B7>0),B1:B7)/SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7="NSW"),(B1:B7>0))`

Comment: I understand the coercion part, and have always preferred "*", but what I realize I don't understand is what the comma does, and why it doesn't yield a #VALUE error.  I bet you do though.

Comment: Hello Doug. If you use the `"native"` SUMPRODUCT syntax (i.e. with commas) then any text is ignored so while this gives an error -=SUMPRODUCT({"x",2}*{1,3}) because the multiplication of the arrays happens before SUMPRODUCT calculates anything....and you can't multiply by "x" - this formula returns 6, =SUMPRODUCT({"x",2},{1,3}) because "x" is ignored (effectively treated like zero)

Comment: @barryhoudini thanks.  That makes sense.  SO makes me smarter every day!

Comment: @DougGlancy Barry is without peer when it comes to Excel formulae - I just sit back and marvel.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 and later you can use AVERAGEIFS

`=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B7,B1:B7,">0",A1:A7,"NSW")`